# Overriding 1 column page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, page

This seems like a really basic question, but i want to change the page layout for 1-column pages created in the CMS, how do i do this without changing the layout of the homepage?

To change the homepage i've overriden cms_index_index.xml, and added additional blocks. I want to do the samething for all other 1 column pages, but they need a different wrapper class as follows:

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content" htmlClass="page-main wrapper">
            <container name="main.content.inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="wrapper-inner wrapper-inner--condensed" />
        </referenceContainer>
```

I'm overriding cms_page_view.xml. Am i overriding the correct file because the above change isn't being picked up?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `cms_page_view.xml` is the right file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content" htmlClass="test">
```

Make sure that the container you reference is actually on the page.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add a wrapper container around the content,  i've added the following:  <referenceContainer name="content"> <container name="main.content.inner" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="wrapper-inner" before="-"> </container>></referenceContainer> is this how would add a container to the layout? I'm also trying to add a block for a custom page banner  <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="page.main.banner" template="Amrita_Cms::banner.phtml" before="-" /> neither are working, can you tell me if i'm misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a page containing a list of filtered product collection via CMS, a 2 column one. Layered navigation is not appearing in left side bar for the page (layered navigation is enabled). [I am looking for a solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361815/how-to-enable-layered-navigation-in-two-column-cms-page-with-a-catalog-product-l) and came across this. Going to try overriding cms_page_view.xml :) . If anyone has previous experience on this please let me know. I m using Magento v 2.4 .